# Flash Characters on Screen in Linux

Tags: python, linux, xfce

I have a XFCE 4.6 on kernel 2.6. Is there a quick and easy way to flash a message on the screen for a few seconds?

My Thinkpad T60 has 3 volume buttons (up, down, mute). When I pressed the buttons, I would like to flash the volume on the screen for a second on screen. Can it be done with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[notification-daemon-xfce](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/notification-daemon-xfce) allows [libnotify](http://www.galago-project.org/) clients to show brief messages in XFCE.  libnotify has [Python bindings](http://www.galago-project.org/files/releases/source/notify-python/) available.

As an untested example,

```
import pynotify
import sys
pynotify.init(sys.argv[0])
notification = pynotify.Notification("Title", "body", "dialog-info")
notification.set_urgency(pynotify.URGENCY_NORMAL)
notification.set_timeout(pynotify.EXPIRES_DEFAULT)
notification.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution is to use notify-send (provided typically in package libnotify-bin) from the command line

```
notify-send Hello!
```